# How to write a unit test case which is using return keyword?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am working on Unit Test cases for my class, and I have one scenario for which I need to write Unit Test.

```
 public void CheckModelDetail(ProductModel model)
 {
       if (executeTemodel == null)
       {
            return;
       }

       checkModel();
 }
```

So I am not sure how I can check for `return` statement.

Comment: In the test case, you should make sure when `executeTemodel ` is null `checkModel` is not called. It can be done using mock frameworks or by creating a dummy class deriving from your business class and overriding some of the methods or setting a flag.

Comment: When you ‘return’ your code is expecting a value of something to output.  Your above code isn’t returning anything.  If you just wish to break out of the if block the. Use ‘break’.  However if you are going to return something change your method from ‘void’

Comment: @RezaAghaei, that is Okay. I have to just write a Test case for that if condition which is returning "return". And other things are handling in other test cases.

Comment: what does `checkModel` do? I assume it checks wether the model is valid or something but then what? Does it thrown an exception or something? Is it a public method or private?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible appraoch could be to mock the class, call `CheckModelDetail` with `null` and verify that `checkModel` was never called. E.g., using [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4):

```
var mock = new Mock<MyClass> { CallBase = true };
mock.CheckModelDetail(null);
mock.Verify(m => m.checkModel(), Times.Never());
```

Answer (score 2):

The buzzword here (with plenty of literature out there) is Observable Effect. Usually it's either a state change, a return value or an exception that is thrown (or not).

If, for instance, you want to test that *no exception is thrown* (Observable Effect), then you need not assert on any output:

```
public void ShouldNotThrowException()
{
    var objectUnderTest = new YourClass();
    objectUnderTest.CheckModelDetail(null);
}
```

Try to remove your `if (executeTemodel == null)` clause and you will see that your test fails somewhere in `checkModel` (presuming you access members of your model in there). Any unhandled exception makes your test fail.

You could use [Shouldly](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly)'s [Should.NotThrow](http://docs.shouldly-lib.net/docs/shouldnotthrow) to make this even more explicit:

```
public void ShouldNotThrowException()
{
    var objectUnderTest = new YourClass();
    Should.NotThrow(() => objectUnderTest.CheckModelDetail(null));
}
```

This not only tests your code, but also makes is very clear to whoever reads your test code what you expect.

Should you want to assert that `checkModel()` is not called, you should move this method into a different class and work with a Mock (see [Martin Fowler's TestDouble](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) for a nice overview). But I'm not sure whether you care about that as the *consumer*  of `CheckModelDetail`. You should test *what you want to happen* (i.e. no exception thrown, model accepted as valid, model considered invalid, ...) as opposed to *how it's achieved* (i.e. `checkModel` is not called) in general, so you're free to refactor the implementation as long as the interface does not change.